# MySQL sum last X rows per group

Tags: mysql, group-by, limit, greatest-n-per-group, correlated-subquery

I have the following tables:

**player_records**

```
int     id          (pk)
int     player_id   (fk)
int     round_id    (fk)
int     kills
```

**players**

```
int     id          (pk)
varchar name
```

**rounds**

```
int     id          (pk)
int     duration            // round duration in seconds
```

I need to select **kills/hour** (SUM(kills)/SUM(duration/60/60)) ratio for each player from the last 10 rounds they've participated, provided not every player takes part in a round.

All similar questions that I've found point to [this article](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/), but I haven't been able to apply its tricks to my needs above as I have to limit the records to 10 before grouping.

To further illustrate it, this is how I'd be doing if I needed just a single player:

```
SELECT SUM(t1.kills)/SUM(t1.duration)*60*60 kills_hour_last_10
FROM (
    SELECT records.kills, rounds.duration
    FROM records
    JOIN rounds ON rounds.id = records.round_id
    WHERE records.player_id = 1
    ORDER BY records.id DESC
    LIMIT 10
) t1;
```

Updated with [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f9ea/2) (Those 3 queries represent the expected results for each player. All I need is to know how to get all of them in the same query).

Comment: How are you going to get the last 10 rounds from the rounds table without a date column? Are you going to use the rounds.id column (assuming it is auto-increment) or is there another column not showing here?

Comment: Hey @smilin_stan. The rounds table does have a date column, but I'll be using rounds.id since it's auto-increment, yes. Nevertheless, lemme stress that it's not simply the last 10 rounds from the rounds table, but those that each individual has taken part in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a rank query mysql does not have window functions for this type of results to get n records per group

```
SELECT t.player_id,
SUM(t.kills)/SUM(t.duration)*60*60 kills_hour_last_10    
FROM (
SELECT *,
@r:= CASE WHEN @g = player_id THEN @r + 1 ELSE 1 END rownum,
@g:= player_id 
FROM (
SELECT r.player_id,r.id,r.kills, rs.duration
 FROM  records r
 JOIN rounds rs ON rs.id = r.round_id
 ORDER BY r.player_id ASC,r.id DESC
) t1
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @g:=NULL,@r:=NULL) t2
) t
WHERE rownum <= 10
GROUP BY t.player_id
```

---

### [`Fiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f9ea/10)

Above query will give ranks to the record which belongs to same player_id  group and in parent query you can limit records to 10 for each player_id and the perform your aggregation logic note that `ORDER BY r.player_id,r.id DESC` is important to order results by player and then its records in descending manner,if you need player names then join players in parent query

Comment: Thanks Khalid, but this query resulted in an all time kills/duration calc. It didn't limit it to the last 10 rounds each player took part in.

Comment: @RZB i have proposed you the rank query and it should do what you ask for also its better can you provide me the sample data set to test and  the expected result set ,more better if you can add the related schema with data @[**`SQL Fiddle`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/) thanks

Comment: Ok, I've edited the question to include fiddle. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @RZB i have updated my query please [`see demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f9ea/10) hope it will work for you as well

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks a bunch, Khalid. Now I'll try to understand what the hell you did there as I'm not familiar with SQL syntax for CASE and variables.

Comment: Love this solution.  Thanks so much for posting.  I would like to turn this query into a view, but MySQL does not like the variable in the view query.  Can you think of any way to get around this?